# Powershell not recognizing conda as cmdlet, function, or operable program

Tags: python, powershell, conda

I've been having this issue on my new laptop for a couple of hours and cannot figure out what's causing it. I'm trying to install scikit-learn with conda and get the following error

```
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
```

the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Has anybody else had a similar issue on Windows 10?

Comment: what version of powershell are you using? if you are on windows this is what it says about installing this product :The WinPython project distributes scikit-learn as an additional plugin.

Comment: I'm using PowerShell 5.1

Answer (score 2):

Have you already activated the environment for this use case?

There is a long running thread about this on the GitHub conda discussion regarding conda failures various Windows 7 and higher, here:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626

One suggestion is:

> The down and dirty:
>
> 1. Check to see if activate works in cmd.exe.
> 2. If doesn't work or not acceptable--as @TurboTim shows:
>
>    Powershell needs the path to each env (anaconda3\envs\someenv\py33.exe. Laborious! :p
>
>    If you don't mind polluting your powershell a little, you can create a profile script which is run every time you open powershell. 
>      The below will add the functions Invoke-CmdScript, Conda-Activate, Conda-Deactivate to your powershell. See Tim's link above for why.
>
>    PS C:> New-Item -Path $profile -ItemType File -Force
>
> This creates a script at:

```
PS C:\> echo $profile
```

> ...something like C:\Users\yourUser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
>    Edit that script.

```
PS C:\> explorer $profile
```

> Add this code, save, and reopen powershell (or . $profile ) :

```
function Invoke-CmdScript {
  param(
    [String] $scriptName
  )
  $cmdLine = """$scriptName"" $args & set"
  & $Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe /c $cmdLine |
  Select-String '^([^=]*)=(.*)$' | ForEach-Object {
    $varName = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
    $varValue = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    Set-Item Env:$varName $varValue
  }
}
$condaRoot = "$Env:USERPROFILE\Anaconda3"
function Conda-Activate([string]$condaEnv) {Invoke-CmdScript $condaRoot\Scripts\activate.bat $condaEnv}
function Conda-Deactivate {Invoke-CmdScript $condaRoot\Scripts\deactivate.bat}


Usage:
C:\> Conda-Activate TFTheano
C:\> Conda-Activate root
C:\> conda info --envs
```

> Disclaimers: Deactivate, as written, didn't do the job for me, thus I just use Conda-Activate to move around. Also, 
>   I don't suspect there are security cautions with adding Invoke-Cmd to profile, so please chime in if 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

I found this online: Unblock-File -Path .\Get-RemoteProgram.ps1
I'm going to try that command in power shell as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I previously had Python installed before conda and since having both together is said to be bring complications I uninstalled the original Python interpreter. This is what worked for me when the same error came up while trying to run a python script using conda.

TLDR; Simply add the path of conda.exe to the environment variables.